# Cannot install Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, installation, android-emulator

I have Windows 10 Enterprise Edition, also Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition. I activated Hyper-V in Programs and Features. So now I can`t imagine why I get this error.

[Here is the error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zSiz.jpg)

Comment: You should install linux;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the error message, you can check the system requirements for Windows Phone Emulator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx

1. 64-bit version of the Pro edition of Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows10 or higher and other system requirements
2. Since you enabled Hyper-V in Windows, but you also need to enable Hyper-V in BIOS. Check your computer’s BIOS is matches the requirements or not, if not, you have to enable these requirements manually then enable Hyper-V in BIOS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx
3. The Hyper-V must be installed and running
4. Your account have to be a members of the local Hyper-V administrators group

Comment: Thanks, I just have virtualization disabled in BIOS.

Comment: @HovsepMikayelyan, it works or you still met this error?

Comment: Yes it works fine. I enabled Hardware assisted virtualization from BIOS and everything goes fine) Thanks for help.

Comment: @HovsepMikayelyan, since your issue is solved through my solution, could you please mark it as answer and it will help other members to easier search it.